# Failed to connect to the SQL Server database in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am new to php and I have a problem. I'm trying to connect to the database of my project and appears every time the error 500 Internal Server Error. The version of PHP is 5.5.9 and the application is an Apache version 2.4.7 Ubuntu server. Can anyone help me? The following piece of code that make the connection:

```
$connect_mssql = mssql_connect(192.168.101.7,'usertest','test') or die('Error connecting to the database');
```

The variable `$connect_mssql` is not returning any value in case of connection failure.

Comment: version 5.5.9 does not support `mssql_connect()`. Try `sqlsrv_connect()`. Make sure you installed correct library. See: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php. Also, enable `display_errors` to show errors.

Comment: Check if your mysql has permissions setted to receive conections from other servers.

Comment: the permissions are all ok and in the case of sqlsrv_connect (), it is supported by Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

`mssql_connect()` is [not available after PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php).

If you are using version 5.5.x, please install `sqlsrv` library which can be download at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx

It does not support Linux servers ( including Ubuntu Linux ).

Comment: how do I install this driver? I am beginner and I'm having trouble

Comment: I read, but there explains the installation on Windows, and I was wondering in my case I use Ubuntu

Comment: how can I solve this problem of mine then using the mssql same since I can not use the sqlsrv?

Comment: I am already using and still persists the error, some other solution ?

Comment: Update your question to show your Free TDS changes.